# getting JSON data without object mapping using RestKit 0.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, rest, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to call a RESTful web service with `RESTKit 0.2` that returns only a string, but the `RKResponseDescriptor` class forces me to use a mapping with its method `responseDescriptorWithMapping` in order to be able to get the string value, I created the mapping and got the string value without any problems, but how can i get this string value without having to create the object mapping (i.e. creating an `NSObject` subclass, creating a property for the string to be received, and creating a mapping dictionary between the returned JSON key and this property) ?

Comment: So you want the raw NSString returned? Or the JSON mapped into NSArray / NSDictionary?

Comment: In either case, why are you using RestKit?.

Comment: no I need the row NSString, Im using RestKit in various parts in the app, until I faced this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, don't use RestKit to make the request. RestKit uses [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the underlying network communications so if you import the classes you can use it too. Try directly using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to make the request.

Comment: I got the response as : {"myString":this is a test} , do I have to do string manipulations in order to get the raw value, which is in this case "this is a test" ?

Comment: So you do want the JSON mapped into the NSDictionary so you can extract the value... Then you want to use AFJSONRequestOperation.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use RestKit to make the request. Sometimes it makes sense to do so in case server is returning an error for example, in which case it is necessary to access the raw data returned from server.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:kLoginURL
                                       parameters:params
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              NSError *error;
                                              NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                                              NSLog(@"msg: %@", [json objectForKey:@"msg"]);
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          }];
```